# Entity Framework: Как удалить запись из бд?

Tags: entity-framework

В проекте используется [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) версии 6.1.3.

В разных источниках я видел различные способы для удаления записи из бд:

1. *Пометить* объект как удаленный: `_context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;`
2. Воспользоваться методом `Remove()`: `_context.Set<T>().Remove(obj);`

В обоих случаях удаление произойдет при следующем вызове метода `SaveChanges()`

Пытался найти в чем различия у данных способов: ничего вразумительного я найти не смог.

Подскажите в каких случаях принято использовать тот или иной способ, может есть какие то ньюансы/рекомендации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод Remove проверяет статус сущности перед удалением и не дает удалить сущности, не присоединенные к контексту:

```
var foo = new Foo();
_context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted; // даст непонятный DbUpdateException при сохранении изменений
_context.Set<T>().Remove(foo); // даст InvalidOperationException сразу
```

С другой стороны, явное присвоение статуса может помочь когда надо удалить запись по ключу:

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = 1 };
_context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted; // удалит запись номер 1
_context.Set<T>().Remove(foo); // все еще InvalidOperationException
```

Comment: т.е. способ номер один будет *быстрее*, единственное что следует помнить о связанных сущностях, т.е. они быть должны подгружены для корректного удаления иначе поймаем исключение, так?

Comment: @Bald *очень* незначительно. Если речь заходит об ускорении EF - начинать надо с отключения автодетекта изменений - а не с удаления защитных проверок.

Comment: @Bald про связанные сущности - не понял. Но ситуация с ними при обоих способах работы ничем не отличается.

Comment: например `public class RequestHistory { public int Id {get;set;} public int RequestId {get;set; }}` в этом случае удаления не произойдет если свойство `RequestId` не будет заполнено

Comment: @Bald с чего бы?

Comment: речь идет не об ускорении, а попытка разобраться в каких случаях какой способ использовать более правильно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44775/discussion-between-bald-and-pavel-mayorov).